# Grouping circular unions of elements

Tags: python, union

Sorry my title isn't clear, and thus it might also be a duplicate...

I have duos of letters and I would like to group into larger lists the duos sharing letters in a closed circular way.

```
Input
[(X, Y), (X, Z), (Y, Z), (A, B), (B, C), (A, C)]

Output
[(X, Y, Z), (A, B, C)]


Input
[(X, Y), (X, Z), (A, Z), (A, B), (B, C), (A, C)]

Output
[(X, Y), (X, Z), (A, Z), (A, B, C)]


Input
[(X, Y), (X, C), (Y, C), (A, B), (B, C), (A, C)]

Output
[(X, Y, C), (A, B, C)]
```

The order of the ouput doesn't matter. I gave example with list of tuple, but it can be another data structure.

The current solution is a mess with if / else statement... I'm pretty sure some functions unknown to me can do that... Can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Really sorry that I can't describe this problem with words... Example are clearer. With the one in comments:

```
Input
[(X, Y), (X, C), (Y, C), (A, B), (B, C), (A, C), (B, D)]

Output
[(X, Y, C), (A, B, C), (B, D)]
```

Comment: What happens if there is more than one way of grouping? If e.g.: in the last input there was also a *(B, D)* and *(D, A)*?

Comment: I think this is finding the 3-cycles in a graph.

Comment: @CristiFati See edit. The (B, D) would be left alone since D isn't shared in others duo.

Comment: @DanD. Possible, I look what it is (EDIT: Yeah it looks like cycle graph theory, thanks for pointing it out). HOWEVER, my example were limited to group of 3, but there could be 4 or 5 letters in the same group. The cycle can be of size N.

Comment: So it is finding the cycles in a graph. Not just for N=3. Then there isn't a special case. I suggest perhaps [the cycle finding functions in networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.cycles.html).

Comment: @DanD. Definitely it. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll have a look at the function you linked as well. Feels good to finally have the right theory behind it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function does the job, but order is not preserved:

```
a = [('X', 'Y'), ('X', 'Z'), ('Y', 'Z'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'C')]
b = [('X', 'Y'), ('X', 'C'), ('Y', 'C'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'D')]

def combine(array):
    result = []

    for i, j in zip(array, array[1:]):
        if any(k in i for k in j):
            new = tuple(set(i+j))
            if not result:
                result.append(new)
            else:
                result.append(tuple(set(result.pop() + new)))
        else:
            result.append(j)

    return result

print(combine(a))
print(combine(b))

#[('Y', 'X', 'Z'), ('A', 'C', 'B')]
#[('Y', 'X', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'D')]
```